# Welcome <user name> in Sencha Architect

Tags: json, extjs

How do I display a "welcome " label in a panel in sencha architect 4-1? When a user logs in, they should be able to see "Welcome " + UserName in a panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Drag a `Ext.form.Label` on a form.
2. Drag a `Basic Event Binding` on it. The name of the function should be `boxready`.
3. Goto the code implementation and type your logic here.

something like:

```
var user = "1933654";
this.setText("Welcome" + user);
```

Comment: What if the information is pulling from a SQL table which stores the user's information (first name, last name, etc.)... Do I still implement the code the same because I was thinking a controller would be needed.

Comment: The logic can be anything. Data from SQL, Data from JSON. If you have a new question ask it ;).